How to Show Certain Category at Multiple Places
I have ecommerce website, developed in Magento 2. I want to show or call certain category at multiple places.
Example:
Grouts is subcategory and URL is https://xyzabc.co.uk/categories/grouts.html.
I want to call this sub category with same URL under Category Paving - Sub-type: Finishing - Sub-Sub Type: Grout
I want to call this sub category with same URL under Category Floor Tiles - Sub-type: Finishing - Sub-Sub Type: Grout
I want to call this sub category with same URL under Category Wall Tiles - Sub-type: Finishing - Sub-Sub Type: Grout
Currently my developer was done as following for the same sub-category. They created individual sub-category under each category type with different URL. However, the products will be same for Grout, so according to SEO this is not good, even not good for user experience.
https://staging.xyz.co.uk/paving/finishing/grouts.html
https://staging.xyz.co.uk/floor-tiles/finishing/grouts.html
https://staging.xyz.co.uk/wall-tiles/finishing/grouts.html
Please suggest best solution for this.

One option we can think of is to use the URL rewrites tool. See https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-admin/marketing/seo/url-rewrites/url-rewrite
Steps should be:

Create the child categories as you have done on staging
Go into Marketing > search & SEO > URL Rewrites
Add the sub categories urls into the tool pointing to the Grouts category and set the Redirect Type to No so the URL does not change.

That way you can manage the Grouts category and the system will have the link still works.
Make sure to follow the guide so you can have the canonical URL's so there is no issue.
